# How to Handle Encoding a Swift Struct Containing Swift Struct as Property

Tags: struct, encoding, decoding, userdefaults

I have a requirement to persist a preferred `Location` that has been selected by a user. The `Location` contains a few properties:

```swift
public struct Location {

    // MARK: - Properties

    public let identifier: Int

    public let name: String

    public let address: Address?

    // MARK: - Initializations

    public init(identifier: Int, name: String, address: Address?) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }

}
```

The `Address` follows:

```swift
public struct Address {

    // MARK: - Properties

    public let city: String?

    public let state: String?

    public let postalCode: String?

    public let country: String?

    // MARK: - Initialization

    public init(city: String?, state: String?, postalCode: String?, country: String?) {
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.postalCode = postalCode
        self.country = country
    }

}
```

Since I only need to persist one `Location` at any given time, I prefer to use `UserDefaults`.

I have a type that encapsulates a `Location` so that it can be encoded and decoded in order to be persisted by `UserDefaults`. However, I have not created an encapsulating type for encoding and decoding `Address`.

My question is: Since I want to persist a `Location`, which contains an `Address`, do I need to create the encapsulating type to encode and decode an `Address` as well, or would it be more appropriate to just encode and decode the `Address` properties inside of the `Location` when I encode and decode its other properties?

I don't know in advance if `Address` will be applied to other types as a property that may need persisted in `UserDefaults`. I am leaning toward creating an encapsulating type to encode and decode `Address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I should create an encapsulating type to ensure that the `address` property of my `Location` instance can be encoded and decoded. That will allow me to simply call `coder.encode(address, forKey: "address")`.

I found a helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013210/nscoding-with-nested-custom-objects#19013819) after changing my search query terms.